# Population-level statistics on current and 'past' agents of one agent type

Tags: anylogic

I am looking for a more convenient way to gather statistics on an agent population, not only on agents that currently live, but also on the agents that have been removed from the model.

To my understanding, creating a statistic in the Statistics area in the properties of an agent population only takes into account the living agent instances.

The Basic Health Economics model in the example model library gathers statistics on all Person agents who have ever lived in the model.In this model, Quality-adjusted Life Years (QALYs) are calculated. This metric is Quality of Life * Time. In that specific model, in Person, a variable called QoL holds the value for the Quality of Life that is associated with the health state the Person instance currently is in. 
Using a statistic in the population properties field, the QoL of each agent is summed, which is then used as a flow in SD stock and flow as the NewQALY per year flow.

It feels tedious and inefficient that making use of a SD flow for each statistic I want to have that also includes 'past' agents. Does anyone have a better approach than the one in the Basic Health Economics model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this? (following the QoL metric):

1. You create a statistics element called QoLStats (from the analysis palette)
2. You create an event running cyclically every year

In your event you do:

```
totalQoL=sum(population,p->p.QoL);
QoLStats.add(totalQoL);
```

You have to create a new statistics element for each statistic you want to collect... maybe you will want to use the dataset element instead depending on what info you want to collect.

Comment: Thank you Felipe. However, isn't that just a less accurate way? Agents may die in between events so I think you would 'miss' the statistics on those agents. You could decrease the event interval but that would approach the stock and flow method.

Comment: it's not less accurate, it's equally accurate... Anyways, I can't think about a different way really... Unless you collect the statistics directly in the statecharts of the agents using the same method I propose... each time you exit or enter a state you collect the time statistic.. but it really depends on what statistics you want to collect.. your question is quite broad

Comment: if agents may "die" in between, add some code into the "on remove" section of the agent type to record the correct timing... might need to be careful to ensure no double-booking occurs but it is all doable.